# Model loss divagate in CNN

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I have model like this :

```
input_img = Input(shape=_shape)  

x = Conv2D(num_l, (3, 3), padding='same')(input_img)
x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
x = Conv2D(2 * num_l , (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Conv2D(2 * num_l , (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
x = Conv2D(3 * num_l , (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(num_n)(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(num_n)(x)
x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='table')(x)

model = Model(input_img, out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss= 'categorical_crossentropy')
```

So the input is on image, and the output is on vector either [0,1] or [1,0]

On every batch (32) there are half (16) of y = [0,1] samples and half (16) y = [1,0]

When I train the model, for the first epoc it seams ok, but after second epoc the loss become 8.05904769897461 and stays unchanged,...

Can anyone point me in direction for looking for error,...

LOG

```
Epoc: 0 -> After 16 images : loss --> 0.7393792271614075
Epoc: 0 -> After 32 images : loss --> 2.964280605316162
Epoc: 0 -> After 48 images : loss --> 3.9417781829833984
....
Epoc: 1 -> After 3520 images : loss --> 0.021433435380458832
Epoc: 1 -> After 3536 images : loss --> 0.0002159792056772858
Epoc: 1 -> After 3552 images : loss --> 1.620501564048027e-07
Epoc: 1 -> After 3568 images : loss --> 0.00011362092482158914
Epoc: 1 -> After 3584 images : loss --> 6.912153912708163e-05
Epoc: 1 -> After 3600 images : loss --> 2.8850188755313866e-05
Epoc: 1 -> After 3616 images : loss --> 1.978150521608768e-06
Epoc: 1 -> After 3632 images : loss --> 0.0013761096633970737
Epoc: 1 -> After 3648 images : loss --> 2.462566590111237e-05
Epoc: 1 -> After 3664 images : loss --> 9.631225111661479e-06
Epoc: 1 -> After 3680 images : loss --> 3.5186160403100075e-06
Epoc: 1 -> After 3696 images : loss --> 1.7695134602035978e-07
Epoc: 1 -> After 3712 images : loss --> 3.3249550597247435e-06
Epoc: 1 -> After 3728 images : loss --> 1.4156105976326216e-07
Epoc: 1 -> After 3744 images : loss --> 2.0861639882241434e-07
Epoc: 1 -> After 3760 images : loss --> 1.4156105976326216e-07
Epoc: 1 -> After 3776 images : loss --> 0.5784698724746704
Epoc: 1 -> After 3792 images : loss --> 4.078485488891602
Epoc: 1 -> After 3808 images : loss --> 0.07696576416492462
Epoc: 1 -> After 3824 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 1 -> After 3840 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 1 -> After 3856 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 1 -> After 3872 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 1 -> After 3888 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 1 -> After 3904 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
...

Epoc: 4 -> After 4032 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4048 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4064 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4080 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4096 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4112 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4128 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4144 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4160 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4176 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
Epoc: 4 -> After 4192 images : loss --> 8.05904769897461
...
```

[image]

EDIT:

---

My guess for this is :
Model for some reason starts to produce only one result [1,0]. This mean, that in batch of 32, 16 of them are wrong all the time,... thats why same number,... but what cause this "overfitting",...
I have the same number of 1 and 2 class,... why would model decide to only return one,...

Comment: Have you normalized the images before using them for training?

Comment: yes, I calculate X/255,... but I didn't do it 0 centered what I saw in some literature ( X/255 -0.5). Why? I understand that weights work better if numbers are below 1, but could it cause this?